# Calling a method immediately if the condition is true

Tags: java, spring-webflux, project-reactor, strategy-pattern

I have an IStrategy interface as follows:

```
public interface IStrategy {

    Mono<Tuple2<Response, String>> add(final String aString);
    Mono<Boolean> isApplicable(final String aString);
}
```

Then, there are a lot of classes that implement the previous interface. Each implementation of `IStrategy` interface calls a different WS.

For instance this is a `Strategy1`:

```
public class Strategy1 implements IStrategy {
    
    @Override
    public Mono<Boolean> isApplicable(String aString) {

     /*
         do some checks and returns 
         Mono.just(Boolean.TRUE) or 
         Mono.just(Boolean.FALSE)
     */

    @Override
    public Mono<Tuple2<Response, String>> add(String aString) {

     /*
           Calls WS 1 and returns a response
     */

     }
}
```

And this is another Strategy that calls a different WS in the add method:

```
public class Strategy2 implements IStrategy {
    
    @Override
    public Mono<Boolean> isApplicable(String aString) {

     /*
         do some checks and returns 
         Mono.just(Boolean.TRUE) or 
         Mono.just(Boolean.FALSE)
     */

    @Override
    public Mono<Tuple2<Response, String>> add(String aString) {

     /*
           Calls WS 2 and returns a response
     */

     }
}
```

By checking the `isApplicable` method, you can figure out which `add` method to call.

So, for instance:

```
List<IStrategy> strategiesList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(strategy1, strategy2, strategy3);

return Flux.fromIterable(strategiesList)
    .filterWhen(iStrategy -> iStrategy.isApplicable(aString))
    .single()
    .flatMap(iStrategy -> iStrategy.add(aString));
```

Using the previous snippet of code, all the `isApplicable` methods are called. Then a `single` statement is applied to select the only iStrategy that respects the `isApplicable`.

I would like to call the `isApplicable` method and if it returns a true Mono, make the call directly to the `add` method, without calling all the `isApplicable(s)` first.
When an `isApplicable` method is true, the `add` method can be called immediately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you are looking for:

```java
return Flux.fromIterable(strategiesList)
    .filterWhen(iStrategy -> iStrategy.isApplicable(aString))
    .next()
    .flatMap(iStrategy -> iStrategy.add(aString));
```

The `next()` method emits the first item emitted by the `Flux`.